# Table width 100% exceeding parent mat-nav-list

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have the following code to render a table inside a `mat-nav-list`:

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <table>
        <tr>Node Information</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td *ngIf="activeNode">{{activeNode.Name}}</td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AutomationId</td>
            <td *ngIf="activeNode">{{activeNode.AutomationId}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ClassName</td>
          <td *ngIf="activeNode">{{activeNode.ClassName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ControlType</td>
            <td *ngIf="activeNode">{{activeNode.ControlType}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <mat-accordion>
        <app-tree-display  [nodeElements]="nodeElements" (clickedNodeCallback)="clickedNode($event[0])"></app-tree-display>
    </mat-accordion>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I want the table to take up 100% of the width of the mat-nav-list, but when I set width to 100%, it takes up the whole screen like so:

[image]

How can I limit the width to match the parent element?

Comment: Does the parent element have width specified? Even if it is just 100%?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the width of your mat-nav-list, you have to add the custom width you want there, below the border style

```css
    table{
    width:100%;
    }
    mat-nav-list{
    display:block;
    border:1px solid;
    /*width:600px;  this is an example*/
    }
```

```html
    <mat-nav-list>
        <table>
            <tr>Node Information</tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td *ngIf="activeNode">{{activeNode.Name}}</td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>AutomationId</td>
                <td *ngIf="activeNode">{{activeNode.AutomationId}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>ClassName</td>
              <td *ngIf="activeNode">{{activeNode.ClassName}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ControlType</td>
                <td *ngIf="activeNode">{{activeNode.ControlType}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <mat-accordion>
            <app-tree-display  [nodeElements]="nodeElements" (clickedNodeCallback)="clickedNode($event[0])"></app-tree-display>
        </mat-accordion>
    </mat-nav-list>
```

Width:auto (100%) without specifying the width in the style
[image]

Width:600px
[image]